# scp ETA for various files in python

Tags: python, subprocess, scp

I have a script in Python which copies files 'file.rar' from differents servers to my laptop (each copied file will be renamed). The scp order is sent as a subprocess, so it goes to the bg and lets the scp be running in parallel (I have already make the ssh keyfile so there's no need for any password)

```
for ind in range(201,205) :
    finalname = 'fich'+str(ind)+'.rar'
    comm = 'scp user@192.168.1.'+str(ind)+':file.rar '+finalname
    proc = subprocess.Popen([comm], shell='TRUE')
    eval( 'proc' + str(ind) + ' = proc' )
```

I would like to have the individual progress bar of each scp at the same time in the console. I can get one with

```
sts = os.waitpid(proc201.pid, 0)
```

but that will only show one of the process and will hold the script until it finishes. I would like something like this on my console.

```
file201.rar 37%   11MB   2.2MB/s   00:18 ETA
file202.rar 47%   11MB   2.2MB/s   00:28 ETA
file203.rar 27%   11MB   2.2MB/s   00:18 ETA
file204.rar 37%   11MB   2.2MB/s   00:08 ETA
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your use of `eval` here is unnecessary.  Just store your `subprocess` objects in an array: `proc_list.append(proc)`

Comment: Might be interesting: https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py uses [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) for SSH, is dead easy to use and you can pass a callback for progress monitoring.